# xml.parse return null google app script

Tags: xml-parsing, google-apps-script

I am trying parse the xml but result return `null`.

Here is the xml:

```
<feed>
    <title type="text">neymar</title>
    <subtitle type="text">Bing Image Search</subtitle>
    <id>https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query='neymar'&$top=2</id>
    <rights type="text"/>
    <updated>2013-05-13T08:45:02Z</updated>
    <link rel="next" href="https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query='neymar'&$skip=2&$top=2"/>
    <entry>
        <id>https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query='neymar'&$skip=0&$top=1</id>
        <title type="text">ImageResult</title>
        <updated>2013-05-13T08:45:02Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Guid">99cb00e9-c9bb-45ca-9776-1f51e30be398</d:ID>
                <d:Title m:type="Edm.String">neymaer wallpaper neymar brazil wonder kid neymar wallpaper hd</d:Title>
                <d:MediaUrl m:type="Edm.String">http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uzJS8HW4j24/Tz3g6bNII_I/AAAAAAAAB1o/ExYxctnybUo/s1600/neymar-wallpaper-5.jpg</d:MediaUrl>
                <d:SourceUrl m:type="Edm.String">http://insidefootballworld.blogspot.com/2012/02/neymar-wallpapers.html</d:SourceUrl>
                <d:DisplayUrl m:type="Edm.String">insidefootballworld.blogspot.com/2012/02/neymar-wallpapers.html</d:DisplayUrl>
                <d:Width m:type="Edm.Int32">1280</d:Width>
                <d:Height m:type="Edm.Int32">800</d:Height>
                <d:FileSize m:type="Edm.Int64">354173</d:FileSize>
                <d:ContentType m:type="Edm.String">image/jpeg</d:ContentType>
                <d:Thumbnail m:type="Bing.Thumbnail">
                    <d:MediaUrl m:type="Edm.String">http://ts3.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.5042206689331494&pid=15.1</d:MediaUrl>
                    <d:ContentType m:type="Edm.String">image/jpg</d:ContentType>
                    <d:Width m:type="Edm.Int32">300</d:Width>
                    <d:Height m:type="Edm.Int32">187</d:Height>
                    <d:FileSize m:type="Edm.Int64">12990</d:FileSize>
                </d:Thumbnail>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/Image?Query='neymar'&$skip=1&$top=1</id>
        <title type="text">ImageResult</title>
        <updated>2013-05-13T08:45:02Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Guid">9a6b7476-643e-4844-a8da-a4b640a78339</d:ID>
                <d:Title m:type="Edm.String">neymar jr 485x272 Neymar Show 2012 Hd</d:Title>
                <d:MediaUrl m:type="Edm.String">http://www.sontransferler.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/neymar_jr.jpg</d:MediaUrl>
                <d:SourceUrl m:type="Edm.String">http://www.sontransferler.com/neymar-show-2012-hd</d:SourceUrl>
                <d:DisplayUrl m:type="Edm.String">www.sontransferler.com/neymar-show-2012-hd</d:DisplayUrl>
                <d:Width m:type="Edm.Int32">1366</d:Width>
                <d:Height m:type="Edm.Int32">768</d:Height>
                <d:FileSize m:type="Edm.Int64">59707</d:FileSize>
                <d:ContentType m:type="Edm.String">image/jpeg</d:ContentType>
                <d:Thumbnail m:type="Bing.Thumbnail">
                    <d:MediaUrl m:type="Edm.String">http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4796985557255960&pid=15.1</d:MediaUrl>
                    <d:ContentType m:type="Edm.String">image/jpg</d:ContentType>
                    <d:Width m:type="Edm.Int32">300</d:Width>
                    <d:Height m:type="Edm.Int32">168</d:Height>
                    <d:FileSize m:type="Edm.Int64">4718</d:FileSize>
                </d:Thumbnail>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

and here is the code:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27neymar%27&$top=2',options)
var resp = response.getContentText();
var ggg = Xml.parse(resp,false).getElement().getElement('entry').getElement('content').getElement('m:properties');
Logger.log(ggg);
```

How do I get element `<d:MediaUrl m:type="Edm.String">`?

> update: but still not work

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Image?Query=%27neymar%27&$top=2',options)
var text = response.getContentText();
var eleCont = Xml.parse(text,true).getElement().getElement('entry').getElement('content');
var eleProp = eleCont.getElement('hxxp://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata','properties')
var medUrl= eleProp.getElement('hxxp://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices','MediaUrl').getText()

 Logger.log(medUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

While the provider is using multiple namespaces (signified by `m:` and `d:` in front of element names), you can ignore them for retrieving the data you're interested in.

Once you've called `getElement()` to get the root of the XML doc, you can navigate through the rest using attribute names. (Stop after `var feed = ...` in the debugger, and explore feed, you'll find you have the entire XML document there

[image: Debugger view]

Try this:

```
  var text = Xml.parse(resp,true);
  var feed = text.getElement();
  var urls = [];
  for (var i in feed.entry) {
    urls.push(feed.entry[0].content.properties.MediaUrl.Text);
  }
  Logger.log(urls);
```

This also works. Note that you have multiple entries in your response, and this example is going after the second of them:

```
var ggg = Xml.parse(resp,true)
             .getElement()
             .getElements('entry')[1]
             .getElement('content')
             .getElement('properties')
             .getElement('MediaUrl')
             .getText();
```

#### References

- [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)
- XmlElement methods referencing namespace, such as [getElement(namespaceName, localName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml/xml-element#getElement%28String,String%29)
- Other relevant StackOverflow questions. [xml element name with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792270/xml-element-name-with-colon), [lots about XML namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml%20namespace)

Comment: thats work thx for help me out.. i am just know method getelement can you tell me reference for learn this.. once again thx..